# Identify Android Devices in Core Java

Tags: java, android

I am doing a project in core java which pushes some processed files to android devices. So what i need is that i need to identify only android devices connected to my computer and push some files to internal storage.
Assume that the device is already connected and permission to access internal storage is already given in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//**************************
// The UAgentInfo class encapsulates information about
//   a browser's connection to your web site. 
//   The object's detection methods return booleans: true or false.
public class UAgentInfo
{
   //Stores some info about the browser and device.
   private String userAgent;

   //Stores info about what content formats the browser can display.
   private String httpAccept; 

   // A long list of strings which provide clues 
   //   about devices and capabilities.
   public static final String deviceIphone = "iphone";

   // [ SNIP! Other variables snipped out ] 


   //**************************
   //The constructor. Initializes several default variables.
   public UAgentInfo(String userAgent, String httpAccept) {
        if (userAgent != null) {
            this.userAgent = userAgent.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (httpAccept != null) {
            this.httpAccept = httpAccept.toLowerCase();
        }
    }

   //**************************
   //Returns the contents of the User Agent value, in lower case.
   public String getUserAgent()
   { 
       return userAgent;
   }

   //**************************
   // Detects if the current device is an iPhone.
   public boolean detectIphone()
   {
        //The iPod touch says it's an iPhone! So let's disambiguate.
        if (userAgent.indexOf(deviceIphone) != -1 && !detectIpod()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
   }

   // [ SNIP! Other functions snipped out ] 

}
```